# Bokeh Geographical Data Visualization

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I was trying to find a module to visualize some geographical data in python. So I was trying to use bokeh library for this purpose. But when I was learning how to use Bokeh lib from their user guide I got some error. The code I was trying to run is :

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 2000000), y_range=(1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")

p.add_tile("CartoDB Positron", retina=True)

show(p)
```

And it raised:

```
ValueError: failed to validate TileRenderer(id='1041', ...).tile_source: expected an instance of type TileSource, got CartoDB Positron of type str
```

Athough the code is just copied from their tutorial it doesn't work.
Versions of the env:

- Python v3.7.7
- Bokeh v2.4.3

This is possible because of the xyzservices which bokeh is calling but it seems bokeh doesn't aware of the problem.
Here is the user guide page on bokeh:

[https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/topics/geo.html][1]

So what do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation example is the example of the latest Version. (>3.0.0)

I found this slightly altered example for 2.4.3 (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/user_guide/geo.html#userguide-geo):

```
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON, get_provider

output_file("tile.html")

tile_provider = get_provider(CARTODBPOSITRON)

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

show(p)
```